# EXC_BAD_ACCESS after storing an object into List in RealmSwift

Tags: ios, swift, list, swift3, realm

I am storing data into Realm, where I have a List of goals inside a game object:

Goal.swift

```
class Goal : Object {
    dynamic var scoreTime = Date()
    dynamic var scoreBy:Player?
    dynamic var scoreForTeam:GameTeam?
    dynamic var homeScoreAfter:Int = 0
    dynamic var awayScoreAfter:Int = 0
    let passers = List<Player>()
}
```

Game.swift

```
class Game : Object {
    dynamic var startDate:Date? = nil
    dynamic var endDate:Date? = nil
    dynamic var homeTeam:GameTeam?
    dynamic var awayTeam:GameTeam?
    let goals = List<Goal>()
}
```

I am adding a goal into Game's goals-property, but the goals-list seems to be invalidated after the saving happens. Here is the code:

```
let toCreate = Game()

toCreate.homeTeam = GameTeam()
toCreate.awayTeam = GameTeam()

toCreate.startDate = Date()

let goal = Goal(scoreBy: allPlayers[0].player, scoreForTeam: toCreate.homeTeam!, passedBy: [], scoreTime: Date(), homeScoreAfter: 1, awayScoreAfter: 0)
toCreate.goals.append(goal)

let realm = try! Realm()

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(toCreate)
}
```

However after `realm.write` call I am facing this error:

```
(lldb) po toCreate.goals

expression produced error: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

And I cannot consume the list of goals any more. It prints fine before realm.write is completed. Is there something trivial I am missing here...? The other parts of the objects play out just fine.

EDIT: so somehow the problem is the property `Goal.passers`- removing it from the object fixes the issue. Can this be related into having quite many references to player in the object hierarchy? See, `Game.homeTeam.players`, `Goal.scoreBy` and `Goal.passers` have the references to player objects.

Comment: how you instantiate toCreate object?

Comment: ah true! Just edited my code to include some basic setup of the game as well.

Comment: @AntonNovoselov also looks like the realm is still somehow messed up after the restarting the app. adding `print(String(describing: realm.objects(Game.self)))` to AppDelegate crashes the app instantly with the same error. I am running realm 2.7.0 on xcode 8.3.2 btw, and running on simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gonna need to answer my own question. My issue was in the custom init code of the `Goal`-object, as it looked like this:

```
    init(scoreBy:Player, scoreForTeam:GameTeam, passedBy:[Player]?, scoreTime:Date, homeScoreAfter:Int, awayScoreAfter:Int) {
        super.init()
        ... 
    }
```

This code does not produce such an realm object that works properly. Creating the `Goal`-object inline without own init-method solved the issue.

---

EDIT: The behaviour itself is weird though - should that constructor work, or is this a bug in Realm?

Comment: @DávidPásztor ah sorry, I accidentally copypasted the return value from my fixed code.